# problema al enviar correo electronico usando yii framework

Tags: php, phpmailer, yii2

quiero enviar un correo electrónico con mi aplicación pero no se envia el correo electronico. Esto es lo que tengo "programado" en el archivo config/web.php estoy usando yii
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Emma, pero despues de un año registrada aquí, ya deberías saber que el código debe incluirse como texto formateado, no como imágenes. Tus tachaduras en rojo puedes ponerlas como XXXXXXXXX y listo.

Comment: Por otro lado, ¿has comprobado si esa librería yii  te devuelve el error que puede estar produciendose al intentar enviar?

Comment: [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53150148/2553194) pone que para Gmail puedes necesitar parámetros adicionales debido a sus condiciones de seguridad.

Comment: Si lo siento mucho se me olvidó adjuntar el código en forma de texto se me fue el avión no disponía de mucho tiempo para enviar la pregunta